# How to enforce initialization of class variables without a constructor?

Tags: php, oop

I have two classes:

**abstract Entity**, **abstract ClassA extends Entity**, **ClassB extends ClassA**

Entity is an generic class for all kinds of entities, such as Cars or Students. There is an static class variable called `$_entity_name`, which contains the exact class name of the entity in the ER diagram.

The big problem: Entity can't set the value of this variable, but uses it! So I *must* define it in Entity, but I can't redefine it in ClassA.

ClassA is the auto-generated base class of an special ORM entity (lets say "Student"). The user is supposed to subclass this base class to add his own business logic.

ClassB is created by the user and extends ClassA. That's the place where he adds his business logic. He's not supposed to touch `$_entity_name` or set this value.

The only way I see is this:

ClassA defines an init() method which initializes these "system level" instance variables to reasonable values.

I want the user to not have to think at all about calling anything which is unusual. I don't know if it's usual in PHP to explicitely also call the constructor of the parent class, or not. But I guess it isn't.

Questions:
A) What's the most convenient way to call init() after instantiation of the class?
B) Is there a way to achieve that in such a way, that the user who creates ClassB must not think at all about calling init()?
C) What other options do I have?

Comment: With regards to calling a parent constructor. If the parent class has a constructor defined and the child class doesn't, the parent's constructor will be called when creating an object of the child class. You can also define a constructor in the child class that calls the parent constructor { parent::__construct(); } and then additionally do other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly an answer to your question but maybe a solution for your problem:
Instead of having a property containing the actual class name (that's what you wanted, isn't it?) you can use [get_called_class()](http://docs.php.net/get_called_class) (as of php 5.3.0) to get the name of the class for which the static function has been called.

```
 class Entity {
   public static function foo() {
     echo 'name=', get_called_class(), "\n";
   }
 }

 class ClassA extends Entity { }
 class ClassB extends ClassA { }

 Entity::foo();
 ClassA::foo();
 ClassB::foo();
```

prints

```
 name=Entity
 name=ClassA
 name=ClassB
```

Comment: Although it sounds good, unfortunately I didn't ment the PHP class, but the Entity name in the ER diagram. It's a little bit different.

Comment: I.e. the developer _has to_ provide a meaningful value, something that cannot be deducted from the information your class can get when the property is used for the first time? Something more or less like `abstract public static $_entity_name;` (which isn't available in php)?

Answer (score 1):

It is actually fairly common to call the parent constructor using `parent::__construct()`.  Would it be acceptable for you to do the following?

```
class B extends A { 
    function __construct($entity_name = '') {
        parent::__construct($entity_name);
    }
}

abstract class A extends Entity { 
    function __construct($entity_name = '') {
        parent::__construct($entity_name);
    }
}

abstract class Entity { 
    static $entity_name;
    function __construct($entity_name = '') {
        self::$entity_name = $entity_name;
    }
}

$b = new B('my_name');
```

Comment: Thanks, but ClassB is part of the business logic layer and created by the user, and thus not supposed to mess with the framework logic. Under any other circumstance this would be great, though!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your question: you have `ClassB` that is a subclass of `ClassA` and when a `ClassB` object is instantiated, you want to have a method (e.g. `init()`) to be called on `ClassA` level without having your user write anything of that sort in `ClassB` code.

**That is what constructors are for.**

However, you hinted that since `ClassB` would be written by your user, you don't want to force him/her to call `parent::__construct()` from ClassB's constructor, so that's the reason why you thought of using `init()` method and also why you are looking for a way to have `init()` to be automagically called the way `__construct()` is, am I right? So, how about this:

- add empty `init()` method in `ClassA` that the user has to overload when he/she writes `ClassB`
- do the stuff you wanted to do in ClassA's `__construct()` (e.g. initialize `$_entity_name`) in ClassA's `__construct()` **plus** call `$this->init()`.
- set ClassA's `__construct()` as `final` so that the user can't overload the constructor.
- tell your users that they have to overload the `init()` method to do custom initialization for subclasses of `ClassA`

pros: you can have the initialization stuff done by `ClassA` without having the user to write anything.

cons: your user cannot overload `__construct()` but can overload `init()` instead to do custom initialization in for `ClassB`

Answer (score 0):

VolkerK's answer is the right one - but you could also look at the instanceof operator and the get_class() functions.

"unfortunately I didn't ment the PHP class, but the Entity name in the ER diagram. It's a little bit different" (openfrog)

That's a completely different problem, however (assuming you can't fix this defect in your entity naming system) mapping entries between 2 lists is a no-brainer.

Your solution of using a property at run-time is very messy and inflexible. It relies on an implicit mapping, the details of which are scattered all over your codebase and any non-linear heuristic will be very difficult to maintain/debug (e.g. if more than one class maps to the same entity in your ERD).

C.

Answer (score 0):

Underneath ClassB, I see two ways to ensure initialization of ClassA:

1. instruct that ClassB's constructor either calls `parent::__construct()` or does not exist.
2. create a hook `init` function that is called by ClassA and implemented by ClassB.  This way, ClassA handles initialization of ClassA in `__construct()` and ClassB with `$this->init()`

Answer (score 0):

This suggestion can't be overridden which would suit your needs.

```
Class A{
   final public function __construct() {
       // do your stuff here

       // optionally add something like this:
       $rc = new ReflectionClass($this);
       if(in_array('init', $rc->getMethods()) {
           $this->init();
       }
   }
```

If it doesn't do what you want (i.e. you'd like classes deriving from `A` to be able to use `__construct()`), you should think about encapsulating your class instead of inheriting from it.

Answer (score 0):

there is an additional way and/or ways for this!

I found it useful by making an instance of function that returns an immediate `new` instance of class like this:

```
class Foo {
    public $name;
    public $age;
    public function __construct($nameArg, $ageArg) {
        $this->name= $nameArg;
        $this->age= $ageArg;
    }
    public function bar() {
        return "Hello, ".$this->name."! Are you really ".$this->age." years old?";
    }
}
function foo($name, $age) {
    return new Foo($name, $age);
}

// And then you can do:
echo foo("john", 22)->bar(); // outputs: "Hello, john! Are you really 22 years old?";
echo foo("caroline", 27)->name; // outputs: caroline
echo foo("caroline", 27)->age; // outputs: 27
```